# How to inspect a Tensorflow .tfrecord file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have a `.tfrecord` but I don't know how it is structured. How can I inspect the schema to understand what the `.tfrecord` file contains?

All Stackoverflow answers or documentation seem to assume I know the structure of the file.

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
file = tf.train.string_input_producer("record.tfrecord")
_, serialized_record = reader.read(file)

...HOW TO INSPECT serialized_record...
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Found it!

```
import tensorflow as tf

for example in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator("data/foobar.tfrecord"):
    print(tf.train.Example.FromString(example))
```

You can also add:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
...
jsonMessage = MessageToJson(tf.train.Example.FromString(example))
```

Comment: It seems that this solution doesn't show all the content of the file.

Comment: Is that so? I didn’t have that issue

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this loops through the entire TFRecord file to give you the contents of one single example. Is there a more efficient way to just read one example?

Comment: `tf.compat.v1.python_io.tf_record_iterator` made this work for me in TF2

Answer (score 93):

Above solutions didn't work for me so **for TF 2.0 use this:**

```
import tensorflow as tf 
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("path-to-file")

for raw_record in raw_dataset.take(1):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
    print(example)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#reading_a_tfrecord_file_2

Comment: Answer should be changed to this one

Comment: This is the one

Comment: I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 206: invalid start byte

Answer (score 11):

Improvement of the accepted solution :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import json
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("mydata.tfrecord")
for d in dataset:
    ex = tf.train.Example()
    ex.ParseFromString(d.numpy())
    m = json.loads(MessageToJson(ex))
    print(m['features']['feature'].keys())
```

In my case, I was running on TF2, and a single example was too big to fit on my screen, so I needed to use a dictionary to inspect the keys (the accepted solution return a full string).

Comment: Is the MessageToJson comes from google protobuf?

Comment: `from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson` is this one

Answer (score 6):

If your `.tftrecord` contains SequenceExample, the accepted answer won't show you everything. You can use:

```
import tensorflow as tf

for example in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator("data/foobar.tfrecord"):
    result = tf.train.SequenceExample.FromString(example)
    break
print(result)
```

This will show you the content of the first example.

Then you can also inspect individual Features using their keys:

```
result.context.feature["foo_key"]
```

And for FeatureLists:

```
result.feature_lists.feature_list["bar_key"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use TensorFlow `tf.TFRecordReader` with the `tf.parse_single_example` decoder as specified in https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data

PS, tfrecord contains 'Example' records defined in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto

Once you extract the record into a string, parsing it is something like this

```
a=tf.train.Example()
result = a.ParseFromString(binary_string_with_example_record)
```

However, I'm not sure where's the raw support for extracting individual records from a file, you can track it down in `TFRecordReader`

Comment: TFRecord files must be read sequentially from the start per documentation.  I'm sure there is a way to read them randomly but maybe no supported standard.

Comment: broken link11111

Comment: @wvxvw, what were you expecting from tensorflow

Answer (score 3):

If it's an option to install another Python package, [tfrecord_lite](https://github.com/jongwook/tfrecord_lite) is very convenient.

Example:

```py
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
   ...: from tfrecord_lite import decode_example
   ...:
   ...: it = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator('nsynth-test.tfrecord')
   ...: decode_example(next(it))
   ...:
Out[1]:
{'audio': array([ 3.8138387e-06, -3.8721851e-06,  3.9331076e-06, ...,
        -3.6526076e-06,  3.7041993e-06, -3.7578957e-06], dtype=float32),
 'instrument': array([417], dtype=int64),
 'instrument_family': array([0], dtype=int64),
 'instrument_family_str': [b'bass'],
 'instrument_source': array([2], dtype=int64),
 'instrument_source_str': [b'synthetic'],
 'instrument_str': [b'bass_synthetic_033'],
 'note': array([149013], dtype=int64),
 'note_str': [b'bass_synthetic_033-100-100'],
 'pitch': array([100], dtype=int64),
 'qualities': array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64),
 'sample_rate': array([16000], dtype=int64),
 'velocity': array([100], dtype=int64)}
```

You can install it by `pip install tfrecord_lite`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the following script: [tfrecord-view](https://github.com/EricThomson/tfrecord-view/blob/master/view_records.py).

It enables a convenient visual inspection of TF records using TF and openCV, although needs a bit of modifications (for labels and such).
See further instructions inside the repository

Answer (score 0):

The answer from amalik works, in addition you can decode the record with whatever method you have already implemented, for example here i can check the images saved in the tf record converting them to numpy array after reshaping them to tensors:

```
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('/content/valid.tfrecords')

for raw_record in raw_dataset.take(1):
    x, y = decode_record_spatial_measureimage(raw_record)

    print(type(x.numpy()))
    draw(x)
```

where i use this method to decode the 2 images in the tf record

```
def decode_record_spatial_measureimage(record):
  name_to_features = {'input': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), 'ground': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}
  new_record = tf.io.parse_single_example(record, name_to_features)

  input_raw = tf.io.decode_raw(new_record['input'], out_type=tf.float32)
  ground_raw = tf.io.decode_raw(new_record['ground'], out_type=tf.float32)
  
  return tf.reshape(input_raw, input_shape), tf.reshape(ground_raw, input_shape)
```