# How to inspect the structure of a TFRecord file in TensorFlow 1.13?

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data, tfrecord

I am rather confused by the TFRecord file format, and how to use it. I have a TFRecord, but have little idea as to what it exactly contains and what its structure is. How can I print and inspect a TFRecord and/or its TFExamples? I am essentially asking the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394585/how-to-inspect-a-tensorflow-tfrecord-file), but the answers to that one are outdated. Printing the `output_shapes`, `output_types` or `output_classes` of my `TFRecord` tells me nothing (why?). The `tf.io.tf_record_iterator()` function is deprecated, but TFRecord datasets now appear themselves iterable (but then why would one still need [the other](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) iterators?). However, simply printing each iteration returns gibberish, and `tf.train.Example.FromString(example)` throws a `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'`. It's all rather confusing. Simply initializing a `tf.data.Dataset` using `from_tensor_slices()` seems so much easier to inspect, and actually gives information on its shape and type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator` to inspect tfrecords file. It creates a generato. To access single example you need to iterate over it:

```py
for str_rec in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator('file.tfrecords'):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(str_rec)
    print(dict(example.features.feature).keys())
```

This will outputs feature names and type(bytes_list in this case)

```
dict_keys(['label', 'width', 'image_raw', 'height'])
```

To output datatypes also, you'd need

```
print(dict(example.features.feature).values())
```

But this will print raw string as well, and you can hit screen length limit.

When you know how it was encoded you can access values by

```
string = example.features.feature['image_raw'].bytes_list.value[0]
output = np.fromstring(string, dtype)
```

You can read more about it here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records

EDIT:
IF eager mode is on, you can directly iterate over dataset object, using either numpy to decode

```
for str_rec in tf.data.TFRecordDataset('file.tfrecords'):
    output = np.fromstring(str_rec.numpy(), dtype))
```

or native TF. `tf.io.decode_raw(str_rec, tf.uint8))`

However, this will give you a flatten array, which will not carry any information about sizes of image dimensions for example

Comment: ```tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator()``` is deprecated in newer versions of TensorFlow; instead ```TFRecordDatasets``` themselves are iterable. ```example.ParseFromString(str_rec)``` throws a ```TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: This function is needed to inspect a file in case you didn't know how it was encoded, so we may assume it's of a limited value. However, it's working in TF version 1.13. Updated with solution for eager mode and TF 2.0

Comment: Ah thanks, now I at least get some values :) You forgot to add ```=np.uint8```, though. My TFRecord is supposed to contain 1200x600 images. I use ```tf.io.decode_raw()```, and I get elements of the form ```tf.Tensor([ 10 238 150 … 66 96 130], shape=(822130,), dtype=uint8)```. However, the shapes vary greatly. Also, I expected 3D/4D tensors, but I get 1D tensors. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I not specified dtype because i don't know which one you're using. AS for shape, as i said it's because array was serialized and then restored. So it needs to be reshaped

Comment: Apologies, I missed that part.

Comment: So there's no shape data in TFRecords files? Which was what my original question was all about. :')

Comment: If it was explicitly encoded it is stored as a feature. You can access complete encoded string with all feature names with `repr(str_rec)` as pointed out in the docs, link to which I provided.